# Check if product already exists in the cart - Cakephp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Friends, I have this method to check if the product already exists in the cart. The same does this, he adds changes the quantity if the product exists, but he also lets the product be sent again.

```
.
.
$order = $this->Orders->newEntity();
            if ( $this->request->is( 'post' ) ) {
                $order = $this->Orders->patchEntity( $order, $this->request->getData() );
                $order->order = $this->Orders->Products->get( $order->product_id, ['contain' => ['Users']] );
                $session = $this->request->getSession();
                $cart = $session->read( 'cart' );

                $counter = 0;
                
                foreach((array) $cart as $cartOne){

                    if($cartOne['product_id'] == $order->product_id){
                        $cartOne['quantity'] += 1;
                        $counter++;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                $cart[] = $order;
                $session->write('cart', $cart);
```

I appreciate if anyone can analyze! I can't really make this filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `break` gets out of the `foreach` loop, but then you append the new order to the cart (`$cart[] = $order`) without checking the `$counter` variable. You presumably want to check that first:

```
if (!$counter) {
    $cart[] = $order;
}
```